# Perl: Easy way to write a Text::Table to xlsx?

Tags: excel, perl

I was wondering if there's an easy way in Perl to write a [`Text::Table`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Table) object to xlsx? E.g. maybe using [`Excel::Writer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX)? I was hoping there is some way to do this easily like somehow casting or converting the table to a hash or array or other structure that `Excel::Writer` will already recognize.

Trying to directly write the table to an Excel sheet does not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Table;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;


# From Perl Monks Table tutorial:
my $tb = Text::Table->new(
    "Planet", "Radius\nkm", "Density\ng/cm^3"
);
$tb->load(
    [ "Mercury", 2360, 3.7 ],
    [ "Venus", 6110, 5.1 ],
    [ "Earth", 6378, 5.52 ],
    [ "Jupiter", 71030, 1.3 ],
);
print $tb;

# From CPAN Excel::Writer tutorial
my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'a_simple.xlsx' );
my $worksheet1 = $workbook->add_worksheet();
$worksheet1->write( 0, 0, "Hi Excel!" ); #Works 

# Now I want to write a table to a worksheet:
my $worksheet2 = $workbook->add_worksheet();
$worksheet1->write( 0, 0, $tb ); # Does not work
```

I know I can iterate through the table and write each entry into Excel, or I could also just write the same data being used to fill the table directly to Excel as I'm creating the table, but since I have a large chunk of code already generating a large table I was hoping I could take that result and dump it right into Excel.

Comment: Write a function what witll take two objects, ($tb and $worksheet) and will do the actual conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `Text::Table` don't allow to extract inserted data, so you need to cheat with the internals. (You may propose to the author of `Text::Table` to add access to stored data as a new feature)

You may try something like

```
for my $col (0 .. $tb->n_cols() - 1)) {
    for my $row (0 .. $tb->height() - 1) {
        #looks like no support in module to extract data, so need to 
        #attack the internals (not good, but may cover the need....)
        my $cell_data = $tb->_cols[$col][$row];
        $worksheet->write( $row, $col, $cell_data);
    }
}
```

Even better if you can get hold of the original array (ie the one you used for ->load(...)

Then

```
my @table = (
    [ "Mercury", 2360, 3.7 ],
    [ "Venus", 6110, 5.1 ],
    [ "Earth", 6378, 5.52 ],
    [ "Jupiter", 71030, 1.3 ],
);
$tb->load(@table);

for my $row (0 .. @table - 1) {
    for my $col (0  .. @{$table[$row]} - 1) {
        my $cell_data = $table[$row][$col];
        $worksheet->write( $row, $col, $cell_data);
    }
}
```